# Why do my Table of Contents and List of Algorithms not appear ?

Tags: table-of-contents

```
\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms

\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

That were running well but when the number of pages ! increased it disappeared :S

Comment: Did you compile your document twice? If the problem persists, please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating your problem.

Comment: Compile * Not Run

Comment: If, for some reason, the auxiliary file .aux was deleted, then you need two compilations to generate the ToC and the list of algorithms

Comment: @Gonzalo: Please turn your comments into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep: done!

Answer (score 2):

Did you compile your document twice? If, for some reason, the auxiliary file `.aux` was deleted, then you need two compilations to generate the ToC and the list of algorithms.